# Error in downgrading Pandas 'Failed building wheel for pandas'

Tags: python, pandas

I try to downgrade pandas from 0.25.2 version to 0.20.1 (because some function now works not the same)
and i got this error: `Failed building wheel for pandas`. I tried: `pip install pandas==0.20.1` . Please help

Comment: Have you already uninstalled pandas (`pip uninstall pandas`)?

Comment: Yes, i have uninstalled

Comment: Can you please post the complete traceback here?